# Identifying location of used time machine file

Tags: backup, time-machine

Running `tmutil status` provides me with the following details on the current TimeMachine activity:

Backup session status:

```
{
    BackupPhase = Copying;
    ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
    DateOfStateChange = "2022-02-04 16:34:41 +0000";
    DestinationID = "B9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    DestinationMountPoint = "/Volumes/Time Machine Backups";
    EventFractionOfTotalProgressBar = "0.1";
    Progress =     {
        Percent = "0.4345236771612808";
        TimeRemaining = "746.5909203181016";
        "_raw_Percent" = "0.4345236771612808";
        "_raw_totalBytes" = 601310056448;
        bytes = 255471616;
        files = 481;
        sizingFreePreflight = 1;
        totalBytes = 601310056448;
        totalFiles = 4300546;
    };
    Running = 1;
    Stopping = 0;
}
```

What I'm missing here is the name of the file that is used for the backup. With multiple files sparsebundle file being available in the destination, *how can I get the name of the sparsebundle file that the Time Machine is using?*

Comment: So to clarify, you have multiple sparsebundles on the same disk?

Comment: @Ezekiel, that's correct. I would like to establish which bundle connects to the Mac I'm currently using.